# How to set menu wallpaper separate from home screen wallpaper

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

I have Samsung Galaxy Note 3,and i think it's rooted.. 
Because it have android version 5.0 mean Lollipop, and i also found "idoneapps" icon in my menu.
So I want 2 different wallpapers, 1 for home screen and another for menu, the reason is the wallpaper which i am using is so beautiful/colorful but when i go to menu the wallpaper is so colorful and i can't recognize the icons so it makes my way difficult.
That's why i want home screen wallpaper and menu wallpaper separate i mean different (i want blank and black wallpaper for menu so that i can see my installed icon more clear)..

Comment: Possibly the easiest solution would be to use a custom launcher like [Nova Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher&hl=de) or [Apex Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anddoes.launcher&hl=de). These launchers let you select the backgroundcolor of the App-Drawer.

Comment: But I don't want to change my launcher, because most of them are annoying, and now i used to Samsung default launcher..